# Turkish character encoding cannot be interpreted properly

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I have a database in which tables are of Turkish encoding as well as pages in which data is shown are of `UTF-8` (I mean while saving as a file). However, as you can see in the second image, the page cannot interpret Turkish letters in the buttons. How can it be fixed? The buttons' texts come from the database. When I go to `Teacher` table, all is alright as expected, but on the page.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed lately the issue by setting the encoding property of `mysqli` in the connection page. *Nonetheless, I don't know what is the default.* It is genuinely interesting since there is no issue like that when I use MAMP db server on my localhost, but on the online server.

```
$mysqli = connect();
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```